# Nightwatch.js writing assertions with client commands like getCookie

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to write a custom command in Nightwatch.js that uses existing client commands, and then pass it to an assertion. However, it's not passing any value to the assertion. I thought it might be related to this sentence from here:
https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/extending-nightwatch/#writing-custom-commands

> The command module needs to export a command function, which needs to call at least one Nightwatch api method (such as .execute()). This is due to a limitation of how the asynchronous queueing system of commands works. You can also wrap everything in a .perform() call.

I have tried wrapping it in a `perform()` call as it suggests but it didn't work, maybe I did something wrong. I have simplified this as much as possible, so that it should always pass `true` to the assertion.

isMyCookiePresent.js:

```
module.exports.command = function (callback) {
    let self = this;

    this.getCookies(function(res) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback.call(self, true);
        }
    });

    return this;
};
```

myCookiePresent.js:

```
exports.assertion = function(msg) {
    this.formatMessage = function() {
        const message = msg || `Checking if my cookie is present`;

        return {
            message,
            args: []
        }
    };

    this.expected = function() {
        return this.negate ? `false` : `true`;
    };

    this.evaluate = function(value) {
        return value === true;
    };

    this.value = function(result = {}) {
        return result.value || false;
    };

    this.command = function(callback) {
        this.api.isMyCookiePresent(callback);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a simple omission on my part: with most commands like `execute`, Nightwatch returns a nicely-formatted object, which contains a value. However, just sending a literal value through the callback does not do this.

Therefore, it is best to send an object to the assertion, with a `value` field, like:

```
callback.call(self, true);
```

Should become:

```
const result = {
    value: true
};
callback.call(self, result);
```

**Note:** Just foregoing the value in the assertion is possible in some cases, e.g.:

```
this.value = function(result = {}) {
    return result.value || false;
};
```

=>

```
this.value = function(result = {}) {
    return result || false;
};
```

However, in this case when the argument is `false`, it will break the assertion on negation (when it expects the argument to be falsy).